# Use Unpack Operator To Split Dictionary into Variables

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to unpack it into two variables by using the unpack operator. Is it possible for one variable to have one key/value and the other variable to have the rest of the dictionary?

```
user = {
    'username': 'charlie', 'email': 'charlie@gmail.com',
    'full_name': 'charlie parker', 'password': '!@#$'
}
```

For example, I tried:

```
*rest, password = user

print(rest)               # ['username', 'email', 'full_name']
print(password)           # 'password'
```

When I tried `**rest, password = user`, I got a SyntaxError.

Is it possible to get the below values using the dict unpacking(**) way?

```
rest = {
    'username': 'charlie', 'email': 'charlie@gmail.com',
    'full_name': 'charlie parker'
}

password = {"password": "!@#$"}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easiest way to accomplish this (but without using dict unpacking) is as follows:

```
password = {'password', user.pop('password')}
rest = user

print(password)
print(rest)
```

output:

```
{'password', '!@#$'}
{'username': 'charlie', 'email': 'charlie@gmail.com', 'full_name': 'charlie parker'}
```